# Usage of "some" with a singular noun

Tags: some-any

Is it correct to say "This verb cannot be used in this sentence. You can look it up in some dictionary"

I'm interested in "dictionary", should we say "dictionary"or "dictionaries" since we have "some" before it?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I interpret “off some wall” in this sentence?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/15196/357) (on ELL).

Answer (score 2):

There is a change in meaning. Check out the definition of "some" at [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/some) and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/some).

In short, "some dictionary" is similar to "a dictionary". You are referring to an unspecified dictionary. But this use also carries the connotation that it's unimportant, which doesn't quite work in this context. Compare with this example: A: "Who was that you were talking to?" B:"Oh, just some guy." Here, B is saying that the guy's identity isn't important.

"Some dictionaries" would imply that you can't look the word up in all dictionaries, only some of them. That also doesn't quite seem appropriate here.

I think it would read more naturally to change "some" to "a", which is your go-to article for talking about something in general.

Comment: Actually, I had a long discussion with someone, and when I got tired with him. I said "go look it up in some dictionary" just to end the discussion. So will that make it unimportant and thus I can use "some" in this case ?